# Variable Size array in MATLAB : How to Generate Variable Size Array from MATLAB?

Tags: c++, matlab

I'm trying to generate C++ code from a MATLAB model.

A MATLAB structure(input to a function), has two members:

```
    struct ABC
    {
       double x;
       double y;
    };
```

Want to convert `x`, `y` values to dynamic size arrays in MATLAB (:?).

In current MATLAB model, `x`, `y` are assigned values as `300`.

So, If I try to use below approaches:

```
    coder.varsize('ABC(:).x ,1);
    coder.varsize('ABC(:).y ,1);
```

*1 -> indicates upper-bound dynamic array.*

Above approach generates the output as below :

```
    struct ABC
    {
      double x[300];
      double y[300];
    };
```

and

```
    ABC.x = coder.typeof(0,[1,1000],1);
```

This approach generate struct with `1000` as upper bound:

```
    struct ABC
    {
      double x[1000];
      double y[1000];
    };
```

Is there any other way to generate, `x` and `y`  values as dynamic values, without upper bound?

Comment: If MATLAB doesn't provide an `ArrayList`, then you may want to figure out  how to create one yourself. An `ArrayList` its a data structure that allows you to access the elements like a regular array; however, it has the mechanism to expand the capacity when the capacity its about to be full. The moment you try to add an element and the internal array of the 'ArrayList' is full, the ArrayList creates a new array, with twice the capacity, copy all the elements of the previous array, and then adds the new element. This makes it a dynamic array.

Comment: Doing some research online, it seems that MATLAB allows you to import Java libraries. So, it seems that you only need to to `import java.util.*;` (if you want all other data structures such as Stact, ArrayList, etc), then you can create the ArrayList with `A = ArrayList();`

Comment: Got the solution. We can do it without using JAVA.    Variable arrays can be created using "typeof()". To create ubounded array, we need to set "DynamicMemoryAllocation" and "EnableVariableSizing" config parameters.

Comment: Great, I would advice to write an answer to your own question with your findings so others can use it if needed.